# How to build and push a Docker image?

Tags: docker, yaml, github-actions

I'm trying to build and push a Docker image in GitHub Actions.

In the YAML file I have other steps as well, which work fine. But when I tried to build a Docker image, the GitHub Action fails. The error is:

```
Invalid workflow file
The workflow is not valid. Job package depends on unknown job test.
```

I have a YAML extension installed in VS Code and it shows no errors related to indentation. If I remove the snippet of Docker build part (after arg command), action test runs successfully.

The GitHub Action error doesn't describe the reason of action fail properly so that I could debug.

```yaml
name: Netlify workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: [master, develop]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master, develop]

jobs:
 build:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  strategy:
   matrix:
    node: [10.x, 12.x] 
  steps:
   - name: Setup node
     uses: actions/setup-node@v1
     with: 
      node-version: ${{matrix.node}}

   - name: Checkout
     uses: actions/checkout@v2

   - name: Setup cache
     uses: actions/cache@v1
     with:
      path: ~/.npm
      key: ${{runner.os}}-modules-${{hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
      restore-keys: |
       ${{runner.os}}-modules-
       ${{runner.os}}-
   - name: Install
     run: npm ci
   - name: Lint
     run: npm run lint
   - name: Build
     run: npm run build
   - name: Deploy
     uses: netlify/actions/cli@master
     env:
      NETLIFY_SITE_ID: ${{secrets.NETLIFY_SITE_ID}}
      NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN}}
     with: 
      args: deploy --dir=build --prod

 package:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: test
  steps:
   - name: Checkout code
     uses: actions/checkout@v2

   - name: Build docker image
     run: docker builder build -t dockerHubUsername/repoName:latest .

   - name: Login to docker hub
     run: docker login --username ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} --password ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

   - name: Push docker image to docker hub
     run: docker push dockerHubUsername/repoName:latest
```

Comment: That error is nothing to do with what your jobs actually do - the job named package depends on a job named test, but *the only other job you've defined is named build*. This is exactly what the error properly describes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for review. I understood my mistake. 
But one thing about downvoting: In the beginning I mentioned that I am a beginner, that means that I am learning and I can do a lot of mistakes. And the guys, who has more experience instead explaining and helping,  downvote and make me and beginners like me more frustrated. Thank you for understanding

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for improving the description. But please, don't remove the bold texts, which makes the description more readable for other developers.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't make it any more readable - less, in fact when you emphasise so many words. And in the nicest possible way we don't care that you're a beginner, just about the content of your posts. As for any downvotes, try not to take them personally, but simple typos don't make for useful SO content.

Comment: The downvoting is because your question does not show any research effort. The error message is clear enough to apply the fix. You have no `test` job defined in your workflow but your `package` job depends on it. Either add a missing `test` job or remove a dependency to it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for help. I learned a lot and will take into account

Comment: @MarcinKłopotek thanks for answer. It makes a sense. It  works. But actually I'm struggling on this test for 2 days and, I did a lot of research. And if my research was not efficient, it doesn't mean I didn't do that.

Comment: It seems that `github actions "depends on unknown job"` didn't have any existing hits on SO, so I've written an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jobs` map in a GitHub Workflow, per [`jobs.<job_id>`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_id), is a map where:

> The key `job_id` is a string and its value is a map of the job's
> configuration data.

Stripping all of the other content out of the YAML to focus on that map:

```yaml
jobs:
 build:
  # ...

 package:
  # ...
```

At the top level, two jobs have been defined, with the IDs `build` and `package`. Now let's look at some of the *content* of those jobs:

```yaml
jobs:
 build:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  # ...

 package:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: test
  # ...
```

Per [`job.<job_id>.needs`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds), the `needs` configuration:

> Identifies any jobs that must complete successfully before this job
> will run. It can be a string or array of strings.

Although it's not stated explicitly, the example shows that the jobs are identified by their IDs, so it needs to be a string or array of strings *corresponding with defined job IDs*.

Here we've said that, to run the job with ID `package`, it "needs" the job with ID `test` to have successfully completed. The ID of the only other job we've defined is `build`, though, hence the error:

```js
Job package depends on unknown job test.
//  ^~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~             ^~~~
//  job_id  "needs"                job_id
```

Given that you have only two jobs and likely *do* want the second to depend on the first, you either need to:

1. Rename the `build` job to `test`; or
2. Change the dependency to `needs: build`.

Either way, the two IDs need to correspond for this to be a semantically valid workflow (even though it's already syntactically valid YAML). An alternative would be to remove the dependency entirely, by deleting the `needs: test` line, although then `build` and `package` would be run in parallel (workers permitting).

Comment: thanks for you putting effort and answer in details. It makes more sense.